# Illegal String Offset within PDO For Each loop

Tags: pdo, foreach

PHP Query:

```
<?php

    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE user_id = :id LIMIT 0, 5');
    $query->bindParam(":id",$id);
    $result = $query->execute();

    $rows = $query->fetch();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo $row["timestamp"]; "<br />";
    }

?>
```

The two rows that should be printed (timestamp):

[image: Database]

What actually prints:
1188((22

The error within the console:
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'timestamp' in /Sites/pages/user_account.php on line 73 - Line 73 being the echo $row... inside the forloop.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [`fetchAll`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) instead of `fetch`.

Comment: You're welcome. According to [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54718/how-should-i-handle-questions-which-are-answered-in-the-comments), I'll post my comment as an answer, so you can mark it as correct if you want to.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `fetch`, which retrieves a single row, instead of `fetchAll`:

```
$rows = $query->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score -1):

You have two rows (user_id = 8)

```
$rows = $query->fetchAll();
```

For all rows

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  echo $row . "<br />";
}
```

For 1 row , all column

```
while ($row = $rows) {

  foreach ($row as $column) {
    echo $column . "<br />";
  }

}
```