# php - Warning: Illegal string offset but vardump shows correct string offset

Tags: php, mysql

After completing a SELECT query on a MySQL database and applying the fetchAssoc() method to the result, I am receiving warnings when attempting to access the results in a foreach loop.  Here is the code:

```
$query=$subquery->execute()->fetchAssoc();

foreach($query as $result) {
  if ($result['active'] == 'Y'){  // (this is line 703)
    $page_id = $result['page_id'];  // (this is line 704)
    if (!$package_pages[$page_id] || $package_pages[$page_id] != $page_id) { // line 705
      $pages[] = $page_id;
    }
  }
```

I inserted var_dump($query) to inspect the results of the query.  Here is an example of the output:

```
array (size=3)
'page_name' => string 'Apts & Rentals' (length=14)
'page_id' => string '49' (length=2)
'active' => string 'Y' (length=1)

array (size=3)
'page_name' => string 'Homepage' (length=8)
'page_id' => string '1' (length=1)
'active' => string 'Y' (length=1)
```

There are 25 arrays output from var_dump($query)

And here is a sample of the warnings:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'active' in ads_load() (line 703 of ...
Warning: Illegal string offset 'page_id' in ads_load() (line 704 of ...
Notice: Undefined index: Y in ads_load() (line 705 of ...
```

Why are the offsets 'active', and 'page_id' being flagged as illegal?

Where is the "Notice: Undefined index: Y" coming from since it is not being used as an index on line 705?

I don't believe this is a duplicate of [Illegal String Offset within PDO For Each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212008/illegal-string-offset-within-pdo-for-each-loop). The issue was resolved when I realized the code given above was placed within another loop which gave the impression I was dealing with an array of arrays rather than a single array each time.

Comment: you need to check if they exist with `isset`

Comment: `fetchAssoc()` returns a SINGLE row of data from the result. you're looping on that one array and trying to access its elements as if they were themselves an array. That means `$result` is a STRING. firs t time it's `Apts & rentals`, next time it's `49`, then it's `Y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're accessing them incorrectly - you've got an associative array and you're trying to loop through it as if it were an array of associative arrays. This is your dumped data structure:

```
$query = array(
'page_name' => 'Homepage',
'page_id' => '1',
'active' => 'Y' );
```

You can get the results directly from `$query`, i.e.:

```
$query=$subquery->execute()->fetchAssoc();

if ($query['active'] == 'Y')
    $page_id = $query['page_id'];
    // ... the rest of your code ...
}
```

You could iterate through the keys and values of `$query`, but since you are interested in particular values from the `$query` array, there isn't much point.

Comment: var_dump($query) outputs 25 arrays.  I only showed 2 examples in the original post. Is that not an array of associate arrays?

Comment: Yes, the array you showed an example of is an associative array, but you're treating it as if it were *an array of* associative arrays. Do you see the difference?

Comment: OK, I see now. What confused me was the fact that the code shown was embedded in another loop. As a result var_dump was showing the results of 25 iterations. My bad. Thanks for the quick replies.